# Convert or simplify expressions with a known value

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-core, expression

I want to write a function like this,

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

Expression<Func<T, bool>> Simplify<T, V>(
        Expression<Func<T, V, bool>> source,
        V value)
{
   ...
}
```

that takes an expression tree and simplifies it. By simplify, I mean take an expression that accepts two parameters, and a parameter value and convert it to an expression tree that accepts one parameter and uses the value for the other parameter.

For example, I might use it like this,

```
var result = Simplify<SomeType, string>((a, b) => a.property.Equals(b), "wibble");
```

and `result` would be of type,

```
Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>>
```

which would represent,

```
a => a.property.Equals("wibble")
```

this result has to remain an expression tree and cannot be compiled.

My problem is I don't know how to implement this function, how do I do that?

---

I think perhaps I need to use [`Expression.Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1.update?view=netcore-3.0) and convert a `ConstantExpression` to a `ParameterExpression` but I can't grok how to do that.

Comment: I think you need to start by fully defining "simplifies". Does it *just* handle the case you described, or does it handle others as well?

Comment: Aha I follow. Every time you see the first parameter, you want to replace it with a literal.

Comment: @canton7 I've edited the question, I hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: @Jodrell I find this interesting but I am first curious about why. What is the purpose of doing this

Comment: @Nkosi I have a class that needs to generically use a filter with a datastore that accepts expression trees for filtering. The filter signature will be the same but, the types and values are not known.

Comment: @Jodrell I ask in case this ends up being an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that could be solved in a different way

Comment: You just need to call the initial three-parameter function.
The new formed expression is a call to a given expression with one parameter from another source.
The same what you do in Source Code if you Wrap `Math.Round(int n)`, with `Round() { return Math.Round(0);}`. You wrap a function call with a new method. You do not modify the given method !

Comment: @Holger, yes maybe, except that I need a expression tree that calls an expression tree. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with an [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=netframework-4.8) which does a simple substitution: every time it finds the second parameter, it replaces it with a constant:

```
public class ReplaceParameterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression match;
    private readonly Expression replacement;

    public ReplaceParameterVisitor(ParameterExpression match, Expression replacement)
    {
        this.match = match ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(match));
        this.replacement = replacement ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(replacement));
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == this.match ? this.replacement : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Then our `Simplify` method extracts the lambda's body and parameters, visits the body to replace the second parameter with `value`, and creates a new lambda using the rewritten body and the first parameter only:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Simplify<T, V>(
    Expression<Func<T, V, bool>> source,
    V value)
{
    var visitor = new ReplaceParameterVisitor(
        source.Parameters[1],
        Expression.Constant(value, typeof(V)));
    var rewrittenBody = visitor.Visit(source.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(rewrittenBody, source.TailCall, source.Parameters[0]);
}
```

Comment: Yes `ExpressionVisitor` is the approach to take. Good explanation.

Comment: Hmm, there is a problem with `node == this.match`, I think that is doing a reference equality check.

Comment: @Jodrell It does do a reference equality check, but that should be fine as we're giving it the reference of the actual second parameter. It worked for me locally, and on DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/imQCSu . Why specifically do you think there's a problem?

Comment: @canton7 what you say makes sense but it didn't seem to work until I changed the condition too, `node.Name.Equals(match.Name) && node.Type == match.Type && node.NodeType == match.NodeType`.

Comment: @Jodrell What input are you using? Can you provide a sample which doesn't work for you?

Comment: I suspect it may be because I'm using an expression bodied property to provide the expression. This may be creating a new instance on each access. e.g. `protected override Expression<Func<T, string, bool>> Limiter =>
            (document, email) => document.Value == value;`

Comment: @Jodrell That would only make a difference if you changed the `Simplify` method to fetch the `Limiter` property twice. Using the code in my answer, a single `Expression` is passed to `Simplify`, so if you call `Simplify(Limiter, "wibble")` then `Limiter` will only be accessed once.

Comment: @Jodrell Can you please provide a full sample which reproduces your issue, either in your question or on a site like dotnetfiddle?

Comment: @canton7, I was accessing it twice, thus making two instances.

Comment: @Jodrell Cool, glad to hear! In future, it's worth confirming that the code provided in the answer is actually broken (by trying it unmodified), rather than any modifications you made to it later inadvertently breaking it.